# Hide vertical scrollbar whilst remaining scrollable

Tags: html, css, webkit

I want the vertical scrollbar for my div to be invisible, but still allow vertical scrolling.

1. I've tried using `overflow-y: hidden` but that disables scrolling.
2. I've tried webkit `element::-webkit-scrollbar` but that affects horizontal scrollbars too.

I would have thought that webkit's `:vertical` state would allow me to do it but it doesn't do anything. See codepen: (https://codepen.io/numberjak/pen/MWgOMqd)

Other questions look at BOTH scrollbars, I just care about ONE scrollbar.

```html
<div class="scroll"><div class="large-content"/></div>
```

```css
.scroll {
  overflow: auto;
  max-width: 20rem;
  max-height: 20rem;
  background-color: black;
}

.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
  display: none;
}

.large-content {
  min-width: 100rem;
  min-height: 100rem;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide scroll bar, but while still being able to scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll)

Comment: Not a duplicate, that hides all scrollbars

Comment: This will be really hard (if not impossible) to do, especially if you want crossbrowser support, as scrollbar-styling is still pretty basic. I'd suggest you use a JS scrollbar, e.g. https://github.com/buzinas/simple-scrollbar

Answer (score 0):

Try this css code..

**css**

```
.large-content {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this helps with my problem

Comment: Its working for remove the horizontal scrollbar? Can u explain it clearly?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to hide scrollbars:

-webkit- (**Chrome**, **Safari**, newer versions of **Opera**):

```
.scoll::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0 !important; }
```

-moz- (**Firefox**):

```
.scroll { overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none; }
```

-ms- (**Internet Explorer** +10):

```
.scroll { -ms-overflow-style: none; }
```

Important points to be considered before hiding the scroll bar:

1. Preferably hide scrollbars only if and when all content is visible else the user may skip the content.
2. Avoid horizontal scrolling on web pages and do not hide horizontal scroll bar as they can make content difficult to read
3. If at all, hiding scroll is required: Display all important information above the fold. Users may often decide if they want to stay or not on what they can see without scrolling.

[Reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll-using-css/)

Comment: These affect horizontal scroll bars too. I ONLY want vertical scroll bar hidden.